# The special point topology is connected?

Tags: general-topology

Is $ =\{ ⊆ X |  =  \mbox{ or }    ∉ \}$ connected?
Here I prove $X$ is not connected. If I show $X$ has separation then it is not connected. If  ∉  then  ∈ V = X -  then $X=\cup V$.  Since $$ and $V$ are disjoint, nonempty open sets the $X$ has separation then $X$ is disconnected.
It is right?
Thanks

Comment: but your $V$ is not open in this topology...

Comment: Since only subset U of X contains p is X then X = U union empty set then X is connected. On the other hand if p is not contained in U then U belongs to T and U also = X. So  X is connected. Right?

Comment: @VuiTinh: Yes, $X$ is connected. If $X=U\cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets, then one of $U$ and $V$ must contain $p$. Say that $p\in U$; then $U=X$, so $V=\varnothing$. Thus, $U$ and $V$ cannot both be non-empty, and there is therefore no separation of $X$.